# Making a function that sums digits within a number

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write matlab function that when a 3 digit number is input, it sums all the numbers within said input.

For example If the input is 213 output should be 6. If the input is 456, the output should be 15. The function should work for any 3 digit number.

Any idea how to start this?

Comment: One way would be to repeatedly use the modulo operator to obtain the least significant digit and add that to a running sum.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this. It uses a trick by subtracting the ASCII number equivalent of each digit.  Benefit is it is only a single line.

```
>> sum(num2str(213)-'0')

ans =
     6

>> sum(num2str(456)-'0')    
ans =    
    15
```

EDIT: To make it a function just do this

```
function out = sumTheDigits(in)
out = sum(num2str(in)-'0')
```

Comment: Unforunately, I need it to be a function!

Comment: @mattryan8524 Just put that line in a function! You'd obviously switch out `213` and `456` for some variable that'd be passed into the function.

Comment: @mattryan8524  See the edit.  Basically what frslm said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo by 10 and keep a counter:

```
function total = sumDigits(number) 
    total = 0;
    while(number > 0)
      total = total + mod(number, 10);
      number = floor(number / 10);
    end
end
```